# Social Signup testing using Protractor & mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, protractor

I am trying to test the signup process for Social sites [google,Linkedin & Facebook] which will run concurrently using same MailId.In mysql DB,I run Queries inside the beforeLaunch:function() in CONFIG file.What is the other approach to tackle the ID=undefined issue when it executes DELETE query from DB?

Config.js file >

```
beforeLaunch:function(){
    var ConnectDatabase = require('../dbconnections/ConnectDatabase.js');
    var connectDatabase = new ConnectDatabase();
    connectDatabase.connection.connect();

    // checking id for created user
    var sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email='+ '\'quantra.learner@gmail.com\'';
    var userID = connectDatabase.connection.query(sql,function(err, result){

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (result[0].id == 'undefined' || result[0].id == 'null') {
        console.log('This user is not available');
      }else {
        console.log('Find User ID by email : ' +result[0].id);
      }

      // deleting id for created user from 2 DB tables

      var sql1 = 'DELETE FROM user_details WHERE user_id='+result[0].id;
      var query1 = connectDatabase.connection.query(sql1,function(err, result1) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('User_details Table : user_id '+ result[0].id +  ' deleted!');
        console.log('affectedRows: ' + result1.affectedRows);

        var sql2 = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE id=' + result[0].id;
        var query2 = connectDatabase.connection.query(sql2,function(err, result2) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log('Users Table : id ' + result[0].id + ' deleted!');
          console.log('affectedRows: ' + result2.affectedRows);
        });
      });
    });
  },
```

Getting error > Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Check what is the data type of result?

Comment: The issue is the value of `result ` is an empty array(`[]`) when no user is available for given email id. you can use `if(result.length==0)` to check if you have any user detail in the result.

Comment: I would like to run Linkedin with same mail id > delete it from DB > run Google signup with MailId > delete it from DB,is there any option available as beforeLaunch() only works one time!

Comment: does the `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` issue fixed?

Comment: As I am running MYSQL queries in beforeLaunch() function asynchronously,its generating that undefined issue but if I changed this approach like running these queries after each signup process,I dont need to check for id=undefined case as of now.